# Get details of Teams Instant Meeting in a channel using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there any Graph API to get all channel meetings in a Teams team. If I use

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)

I get all the messages, including any Meeting that is scheduled. But I do not get any details regarding the instant meeting

I also tried this - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup-id%7D/events)
But this also just gives the list of meetings that were scheduled and are a part of the calendar

I also tried the API - CreatOrGet. But for this we need to pass the 'externalId' and there is no way to get an external id of an instant meeting (that is started using the 'Meet Now' button on top right hand side. Is there any API to get the external Id of an instant meeting ?

Comment: You can get the call details using [Get call API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).